how to arrange telegram inline buttons to be 2 in every row?
I want to set 2 buttons in every row from all my data in Database but I don't know how?
here is my code.
Thank you very much
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    
    $jonres[] = $row['jonre'];
}

if (isset($update['callback_query'])) {
    MessageRequestJson("editMessageText",array('chat_id' =>$callback_username,'message_id'=>$callback_messageId,'text'=>'ali','reply_markup' => array(
        "inline_keyboard"=>array(
            array(array("text"=> $jonres[0],"callback_data"=> $jonres[0]),array("text"=> $jonres[1],"callback_data"=> $jonres[1])),
            array(array("text"=> $jonres[2],"callback_data"=> $jonres[2]),array("text"=> $jonres[3],"callback_data"=> $jonres[3])),
            array(array("text"=> $jonres[4],"callback_data"=> $jonres[4]),array("text"=> $jonres[5],"callback_data"=> $jonres[5]))
         ))
    ));
}


What doesn't work? Whats your current output and how does it differ from the expected one?

This code works for 4 indexes of arrays but what I want is for all database and in a loop which I can add to my database in the the future.
